# How to change the file size using powershell?

Tags: file, powershell, size

I want to change the size of a file to a value that the user will choose. Is there any way to do that? Thank you for your help.

Comment: I didnt try anything because i didnt know how, tried to search online for an answeer but i didnt find anything related. I need to know how can i take a file and change the value of its size

Comment: Change the size of what file? In what way? Are you (or your users) okay with data loss?

Answer (score 2):

Just to get a set off for you. Use **fsutil**

To create a single File use:

```
fsutil file createnew E:\filename.txt 5000
```

This will create a filename.txt of 5MB size

For doing it in Powershell:

```
$f = new-object System.IO.FileStream E:\filename.txt, Create, ReadWrite
$f.SetLength(5MB)
$f.Close()
```

Hope this helps

Comment: And what of its an exsisting file? Make it a variable and .setlength? Tried doing this and "system.Io.filesystem" wasnt recognized, maybe because my powershell is v2?

Comment: create makes the file to create. If existing then it will overwrite. Go through the `System.IO.Filesytem` object. Give a pipe and hit **get-member**, you will get lot more options on that. It will work then.

Comment: @ofribouba: Accept the answer if it helps you

Comment: File Size Changer: [link]https://sourceforge.net/projects/filesizefaker/
Yes .Setlength will do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an existing file it's size is dependent upon the amount of information inside it.  You can't manually change the file size without removing or adding to the information inside it.